# ClassNotFoundException Java Applet

Tags: java, applet, syntax-error, japplet

I get the ClassNotFoundException error when I make my html file with the code and jar file. Not sure why. Here's what I have:

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>
Test Applet
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Test Applet</h2>
<applet
code="Testing.class"
archive="myTestJar.jar" 
width=550 height=300>
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

I simply have the class in a jar file and tried to reference using archive but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<applet code=Testing.class
        archive="myTestJar.jar"
        width=550 height=300>
</applet>
```

The class has your `main()` I assume, the jar is the entire thing.

if,you're not taking packages into consideration. For instance, if the package is myPackage.vol3 then the line should read

```
<applet code="myPackage.vol3.Testing.class" archive="myTestJar.jar"
```

and put the html file in the project folded "INSIDE" the project folder.

Comment: Thanks! I am having trouble doing the package thing however. My main class is in the default package, is that the right place? I have tried to reference a .class file outside a jar file and Firefox reads it but when placed in a jar file, Firefox says .class file is not found. That is the reason I am baffled.

Comment: When you place it in the jar file you have to use archive="myTestJar.jar"